# VM instance is running, project is active, but site cannot be reached

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The VM instance is running and the project is active but the site cannot be reached.
Account was reactivated. I have clicked the start and resume option for the VM instance, but still the site cannot be reached. 2 hours have passed. Google Cloud Support has requested me to escalate it here.

Comment: This is not an escalation path or an official Google support channel. You need to contact Google support with this concern.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with firewall rules and tags.
Refer [troubleshooting webserver on compute engine vm](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache#troubleshooting)